# When working with CTEs, best to filter with join or with in()?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a query that is taking a long time to run. Since this query will be automated with a cron job anyway, that doesn't matter so much and I like the readability of CTEs compared to just nested queries, which in the past I have found do work faster due to predication.

So, I prefer the readability of using CTE's without using sub queries where possible.

Here are three ways of running the same query along with their explain statements. I would like to better understand the explain statement as well as understand which approach is better.

```
with 

/*
cte for filtering all events that happened on this date only
*/
filter_sessions as (
select dimension1
from ga_flagship_ecom.sessions
where date = '2020-01-16'
),


ee as (
select 
    dimension1,
    dimension3,
    case when sum(case when metric1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as zero_val_product -- roll up to event level
from ga_flagship_ecom.ecom
where dimension1 in (select dimension1 from filter_sessions)
group by 1,2
)

select * from ee;
```

Here I used `in()` to filter ee. Explain:

```
CTE Scan on ee  (cost=61757.45..61758.23 rows=39 width=44)
  CTE filter_sessions
    ->  Index Only Scan using sessions_date_idx on sessions  (cost=0.56..2.76 rows=1 width=22)
          Index Cond: (date = '2020-01-16'::date)
  CTE ee
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=61753.72..61754.69 rows=39 width=34)
          Group Key: ecom.dimension1, ecom.dimension3
          ->  Sort  (cost=61753.72..61753.81 rows=39 width=34)
                Sort Key: ecom.dimension1, ecom.dimension3
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.58..61752.69 rows=39 width=34)
                      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.02..0.03 rows=1 width=32)
                            Group Key: (filter_sessions.dimension1)::text
                            ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
                      ->  Index Scan using ecom_pk on ecom  (cost=0.56..61752.26 rows=39 width=34)
```

An alternative is to use an inner join to filter on:

```
with 

/*
cte for filtering all events that happened on this date only
*/
filter_sessions as (
select dimension1
from ga_flagship_ecom.sessions
where date = '2020-01-16'
),


ee as (
select 
    e.dimension1,
    e.dimension3,
    case when sum(case when e.metric1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as zero_val_product -- roll up to event level
from ga_flagship_ecom.ecom e
join filter_sessions f on f.dimension1 = e.dimension1
group by 1,2
)

select * from ee;
```

The explain for this version is:

```
CTE Scan on ee  (cost=61757.43..61758.21 rows=39 width=44)
  CTE filter_sessions
    ->  Index Only Scan using sessions_date_idx on sessions  (cost=0.56..2.76 rows=1 width=22)
          Index Cond: (date = '2020-01-16'::date)
  CTE ee
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=61753.70..61754.68 rows=39 width=34)
          Group Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
          ->  Sort  (cost=61753.70..61753.80 rows=39 width=34)
                Sort Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..61752.67 rows=39 width=34)
                      ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions f  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
                      ->  Index Scan using ecom_pk on ecom e  (cost=0.56..61752.26 rows=39 width=34)
                            Index Cond: ((dimension1)::text = (f.dimension1)::text)
```

Then there is a third option, to use both the where and join:

```
with 

/*
cte for filtering all events that happened on this date only
*/
filter_sessions as (
select dimension1
from ga_flagship_ecom.sessions
where date = '2020-01-16'
),


ee as (
select 
    e.dimension1,
    e.dimension3,
    case when sum(case when e.metric1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as zero_val_product -- roll up to event level
from ga_flagship_ecom.ecom e
join filter_sessions f on f.dimension1 = e.dimension1
where e.dimension1 in (select dimension1 from filter_sessions)
group by 1,2
)

select * from ee;
```

And the explain for this version is:

```
CTE Scan on ee  (cost=61758.32..61759.10 rows=39 width=44)
  CTE filter_sessions
    ->  Index Only Scan using sessions_date_idx on sessions  (cost=0.56..2.76 rows=1 width=22)
          Index Cond: (date = '2020-01-16'::date)
  CTE ee
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=61754.59..61755.57 rows=39 width=34)
          Group Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
          ->  Sort  (cost=61754.59..61754.69 rows=39 width=34)
                Sort Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
                ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.56..61753.56 rows=39 width=34)
                      Join Filter: ((f.dimension1)::text = (filter_sessions.dimension1)::text)
                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..61752.67 rows=39 width=66)
                            ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions f  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
                            ->  Index Scan using ecom_pk on ecom e  (cost=0.56..61752.26 rows=39 width=34)
```

I'm not very familiar with reading explain statements but the 'cost' at the top of each of the 3 is very similar: 61757.45, 61757.43 and 61758.32.

Which is the best approach? Both here and now as well as more generally? Filter with inner joins or filter with `in()`?

```
select version();
PostgreSQL 11.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXISTS` clause always performs faster than `IN` clause. You must give that a try -

```
select dimension1,
       dimension3,
       case when sum(case when metric1 = 0
                               then 1
                          else 0
                     end) > 0
                 then 1
            else 0
       end as zero_val_product
from ga_flagship_ecom.ecom E
where EXISTS (select 1
              from ga_flagship_ecom.sessions S
              WHERE S.dimension1 = E.dimension1
              AND date = '2020-01-16')
group by 1,2
```

Apart from it, for more faster execution, You may try having index on sessions (date, dimension1)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm running that now. I had never heard of exists() before. Question, in your example, within exists you referenced sessions table directly, any disadvantage of referencing the cte instead? `where exists (select 1 from filter_sessions s
     where s.dimension1 = e.dimension1)` I ask because in my actual query, I have several more CTEs that will all need to filter on dimension1 on '2020-01-16' and presumably it's more efficient to pull this list of dimension1 just once like I have at the top?

Comment: CTEs are meant for 2 purposes. To achieve recursion and sub-query factoring. I dont think it is strictly needed to use CTE here. Hence I have used normal sub-query.